# Relating Terms to Meta keys of a Post ID in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Imagine you have a Post Type called "Products" and a taxonomy called "Zip Codes". Products has two meta fields called "Origins" and "Destinations", which each hold multiple references to Zip Codes.

A. If you just use `wp_set_object_terms` you lose which field the zip codes belong to, since this method only relates Terms to the Post ID, not to that ID's meta keys.

B. If you just use `update_post_meta($product_id, 'origin|destination', $zip_codes)` you lose the counts in `wp_term_relationships`.

Maintaining both seems exhausting and error-prone.

**What's the best practice for relating taxonomy terms to the custom fields of a specific Post ID?**

Comment: I'm curious about `wp_term_relationships`. Is there a significant difference between using that and making a meta_query for `origin_zip`? I'd prefer the latter, and a single DB call, when I'm dealing with a semantically 'metadata' sort of data.

Comment: @Benjamin, I'm also not particularly concerned with the count in `wp_term_relationships`, but this use case is not at all unusual, so it me makes me wonder why I'd ever use `wp_set_object_terms`.

Comment: I'd use that for setting a *taxonomy* term, something like `Categories` or `Tags`. I am not confident enough in it because I never need to use it. It seems more closely related to taxonomies than post meta.

Comment: For example, remove all categories from a post: `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, null, 'category' );`